# Adding months to a date when there are 28,29 days in month

Tags: php, date

I am trying to write a function where I can take a date and add to it x months. For example if the date is 2019-01-31 then +1 month should be 2019-02-28. My functions seems to work only if I add 1 month. Is there a way to make it add more than one month?

for example addMonth('2019-01-31', 3) - should be 2019-04-30 (only 30 days in April so stop there).

```
function addMonth($date, $count)
{
    $start = new DateTime($date);
    $end = clone $start;
    $end->modify("+$count months");

    while (($start->format('m')+1) % 12 != $end->format('m') % 12) {
        $end->modify('-1 day');
    }

    return $end->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo addMonth('2019-01-31', 1); // 2019-02-28 is correct!
echo addMonth('2019-01-31', 3); // should be 2019-04-30!
```

Comment: An interesting problem. Look at the answer by @Clinton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `DateTime::modify('+1 month')` will add the number of days of the current month to DateTime object.

You can fix this by adding the number of days of the upcoming month, like this:

```
<?php
function addMonth($date, $count)
{

  $end = clone new DateTime($date);

  $nextMonth = clone $end;
  /*set the date to be first of month to get the next month*/
  $nextMonth->modify('first day of this month');

  for($i = 0;$i < $count; $i++){

    /*get the number of days in the next month*/
    $nextMonth->modify('next month')->modify('last day of this month');
    $numOfDaysInNextMonth = $nextMonth->format('d');

    /*add number of days in the next month to the end date*/
    $end->modify("+$numOfDaysInNextMonth days");

    $nextMonth->modify('first day of this month');
  }
  return $end->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo addMonth('2019-01-31', 1)."<br>"; // 2019-02-28
echo addMonth('2019-01-31', 2)."<br>"; // 2019-03-31
echo addMonth('2019-01-31', 3)."<br>"; // 2019-04-30
```

Comment: This cloning looks really ugly, why don't just use DateTimeImmutable

Answer (score 1):

Let the PHP `DateTime` functions do the heavy lifting for you.

```
$rightnow = new DateTime();
$rightnow->modify('+1 month');
echo $rightnow->format('m-d-Y');
```

If you need variable starting dates you may pass it to the initial call to DateTime on the first line (in yyyy-mm-dd format).

Comment: Not working. This skips february. It jumps to 03-03-2019

Comment: Not to argue but that is the correct date if you add a month to January 31st (today). There are a number of other options if you just want to add a specific number of days or just about anything else. See the user comments about the `modify` method in the [online PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php).

Comment: What's "a month" - It's not the correct date if you add a February's days

Answer (score 1):

The approach used by @Dave is correct if you want to add the number of days in the current month to the current date, but I am not sure that this is what you are looking for. Based on your question and the comments in your code, it looks to me like you want to find the last day of the month a number of months in the future. This is not as straightforward, so here goes. First the solution from @Dave as a function:

```
function addMonth($date, $count) {
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date)->modify('+'.$count.' month')->format("Y-m-d");
    return $dt;
}
```

If the calls are as follows:

```
echo '<li>Start: '.addMonth('2019-01-31', 0).'</li>';
echo '<li>Plus 1 month: '.addMonth('2019-01-31', 1).'</li>';
echo '<li>Plus 3 months: '.addMonth('2019-01-31', 3).'</li>';
echo '<li>Plus 12 months: '.addMonth('2019-01-31', 12).'</li>';
echo '<li>Plus 13 months: '.addMonth('2019-01-31', 13).'</li>';
```

the output will be:

- Start: 2019-01-31
- Plus 1 month: 2019-03-03
- Plus 3 months: 2019-05-01
- Plus 12 months: 2020-01-31
- Plus 13 months: 2020-03-02

If you want **the last day in the month a number of months in the future** the function should be:

```
function addMonth($date, $count) {
    $start = new DateTime($date);
    $start->modify( 'first day of this month' );
    $start->modify('+'.$count.' month');
    $dt = $start->format('Y-m-t');
    return $dt;
}
```

and the output then will be:

- Start: 2019-01-31
- Plus 1 month: 2019-02-28
- Plus 3 months: 2019-04-30
- Plus 12 months: 2020-01-31
- Plus 13 months: 2020-02-29

which is what I think you want. I hope that this helps.